# Error in Table Creation Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-04044

code:

```
create table Penalties (
  PaymentNo number (4) not null, 
  PlayerNo number(4),
  Pen_date date default now(), 
  Amount number(7,2) default 2000.00
);
```

Error information (in German):

```
Fehler beim Start in Zeile 1 in Befehl:
create table Penalties (PaymentNo number (4) not null, PlayerNo number(4),Pen_date date default now(), Amount number(7,2) default 2000.00)
Fehler bei Befehlszeile:1 Spalte:96
Fehlerbericht:
SQL-Fehler: ORA-04044: Prozedur, Funktion, Package oder Typ hier nicht zulässig
04044. 00000 -  "procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here"
*Cause:    A procedure, function, or package was specified in an
           inappropriate place in a statement.
*Action:   Make sure the name is correct or remove it.
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `now()` as default value is not allowed here. Try replacing it with `sysdate`

Answer (score 0):

Change default now() to default sysdate